# Large (20x20) correlation scatterplots in SAS?

Tags: correlation, sas

I'm doing some exploratory analysis on a dataset with 27 variables, of which maybe 24 have interesting numerical content. I'd like to look at a big draftsman's plot to see how each pair interact, however when I try to do something like that in CORR or SGSCATTER it continues to spit out the same 640x640 plot and shrinks the graphs.

Is there a way to make it create a big plot, instead of having to macro through and create a bunch of 6x6?

EDIT - my code:

```
ods rtf;
ods graphics on;

proc sgscatter data=home.byEpisode;
 matrix var1
   var2
   var3 %* and so on until 27;
run;

ods rtf close;
ods graphics off;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear from your question whether this is being caused by PROC CORR itself, or if it's an issue with the output. ODS allows you to adjust the size of outputs, as illustrated at the link below. This permits the adjustment of graphics, but the same is true for adjusting the size of the page you are working on (see reference 2 for a SUGI paper on the topic).

I would suggest adjusting the papersize to something rather large, and then using ODS PDF with the PROC CORR to pipe the output there. Hopefully that should resolve your issue.

1. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_odsgraph_sect034.htm
2. http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/011-2010.pdf

Comment: The output looks polished and lovely, so I suspect it's a question of outputting the right thing in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried using ODS PDF and increasing the size of the page, like the SUGI paper suggests?

Comment: So simply switching to PDF without declaring anything else got me the plot I was looking for, albeit a small cramped version. Also, it gave me a nice large 2000x2000 PNG that I did not ask for (but which is quite nice to have as a raster). Defining a large papersize (20in x 20in) just gave me the same small cramped PDF but on a bigger blank paper.

Comment: In the end, I got the solution I wanted with this R code:
[code]data <- read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

png("chart.png",width=6000,height=6000)
pairs(byep[3:27],cex=.5,pch=20)
dev.off()

log_data = log(data)

names(log_data) <- paste('log',names(log_data),sep="_")

data_w_log <- cbind(data[3:27],log_data[3:27])

png("data_w_log.png",width=10000,height=10000)
pairs(data_w_log,cex=.5,pch=20)
dev.off()[/code]